# How to configure Anychart Qlik Sense stacked bar chart as Butterfly chart?

Tags: qliksense, anychart

I am trying to configure a stacked bar chart as a butterfly chart using Anychart Qlik Sense extension.

This is a description on how to do in Anychart: https://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/Bar_Charts/Stacked_Bar_Chart_with_Negative_Values.php

The main trick appears to be the use of:

`// format y axis labels so they are always positive
    chart.yAxis().labels().format(function () {
        return **Math.abs**(this.value).toLocaleString();
    });`

to get positive values on the y axis.

I can see how to format the y axis labels using text formatter tokens but not how to utilise the Math.abs function within the extension label expression.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the current version of the Stacked Bar chart extension v3.4 doesn't provide the possibility to apply Math.abs-like option for the value. The only alternative we can suggest now is the following string-token: `{%value}{useNegativeSign: false}`. It replaces the negative sign `-value` with brackets `(value)`.
We will take into account this use case for future updates.

Comment: I updated my Data Label expression from:
{%value}{decimalsCount:2,scale:(1)(1000)(1000)(1000)|()(k)(M)(B)}
to 
{%value}{useNegativeSign: false, decimalsCount:2,scale:(1)(1000)(1000)(1000)|()(k)(M)(B)} 
which resulted in the negative sign being replaced with brackets as expected, thanks.